# Huge Bitmaps causing ANR in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Here is the thing:

- I am working with Huge Bitmap [ 1024 X 1024 ]
- I need the BitMap data in ( RGB & alpha ) format for pixel-wise manipulation; for this manipulation I am using native libraries
- Activity works well with [ 512 X 512 ] images ... But when I'm switching between the activities with similar task android crashes with the following trace

The question is this:

- What am I doing wrong ? What should cause JiT resizing ?
- is there a way to load huge bitmaps .. ? if I use the application caching ; would it provide me with some benefit in this case ? If yes , then which memory would caching consume ? Mainly I am hitting the memory limits ... so I am trying to work around that...

The trace:

```
03-22 14:21:05.240: I/dalvikvm(105): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
03-22 14:21:05.730: D/dalvikvm(196): GC_EXPLICIT freed 44K, 50% free 3130K/6151K,external 5368K/6703K, paused 713ms
```

Please Note :

- I'm currently running on API 10 [ there is no scope of using the API 11 or more ]
- I would not be able to use "android:largeHeap" option as well
- As I am using the native library I am hitting the 6 MB limit [ native memory ] , though I am having 32 MB Memory at my disposal...

**UPDATE :** [ ANR Trace  ]

This ANR trace indicates KeyDispatchingTimedOut .. but I believe that's not the reason ... As upon clicking the "Menu" I'm switching to the another activity using Intent.. when this activity starts up it needs to calculate the "Background image" based on the "color array" using a native library... That's what takes long ...
Note when the activity is started individually the same calculation occurs ...

```
E/ActivityManager(105): ANR in com.uc (com.uc/.UcMain)
E/ActivityManager(105): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
E/ActivityManager(105): Load: 2.31 / 1.58 / 1.48
E/ActivityManager(105): CPU usage from 29434ms to 1ms ago:
E/ActivityManager(105):   97% 1737/com.uc: 97% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 117 minor
E/ActivityManager(105):   1.4% 73/akmd: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(105):   0.6% 105/system_server: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 9 minor
```

Comment: one 1024x1024 RGBA image is 4MB in size when loaded into memory. I guess you should just use smaller images. Besides, your trace is no error. It's just info about the internals (though memory related)

Comment: I've added the ANR info as well for the reference... using smaller image/sampling is not an option ... I need full intensity image !! one thing I am not sure about is is there a possibility to create image directly in the native memory ?

Comment: all the `onCreate`, `onClick`, `onLocationChanged`, `onStuffHappened`, .. are executed in the UI thread which you must not stop from checking if there is something happening (or you get keyDispatchingTimedOut). If there is no `Thread` or `AsyncTask` in your code -> everything is UI thread. You should move all the image loading & processing into an `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 4):

ANR is not really a memory problem, it is a problem with doing something on the UI thread ('main' in the debugger) that is taking too long. Any work you do on the UI thread needs to be quick or will trigger the ANR watchdog.  The long running process you are doing that causes this needs to be put into another thread.

You need to move the work you are doing to calculate the background image into a separate thread. I'd suggest you use the approach of loading the Activity with a just a progress spinner and starting your background thread, then you have everything to actually display the UI hide the spinner and show the views you want to be setting the background image on.

Note that you can only make changes to Views from the UI thread, such as calling the API `View.setBackgroundDrawable(...)` , but you can construct the Drawable in a background thread then set it from the UI thread. AsyncTask is good for this pattern of work.
If you don't use `AsyncTask` then you will use the API `Activity.runOnUiThread(...)`

Comment: Agree .. That ANR is not a memory problem but if UI thread is taking too long then it should fail all the time , Right ? If I call the " X activity " first it works .. If I call the " Y Activity first " it works ... But if I call one from other ... ANR happens ... I've tried running them as "SingleInstance" mode as the activities are completely independent of each other..
For you reference I've updated the post with the ANR trace ... Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Just because it doesn't fail when started directly doesn't mean that isn't the problem, it is all about timing. The ANR watchdog is probably more forgiving on the startup Activity that subsequent Activities. As @zapl pointed out, if you have no Threads or AsynkTask then everything is running on the UI thread. For simple stuff this is fine, but generally you want to keep as much work off the UI thread as possible.